# Dragula Drag-And-Drop not working in Aura Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I'm trying to create a component to reorder a set of records. I'm trying to use the library [Dragula](https://bevacqua.github.io/dragula/) to handle my drag-and-drop functionality. However, when the component loads, the drag-and-drop doesn't work. When I drag my mouse over the elements, it just selects the text. I have recreated the issue with hard-coded data:

Component:

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
    <ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.Dragula + '/dragula.min.js'}" styles="{!$Resource.Dragula + '/dragula.min.css'}" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.afterDragulaLoaded}"/>

    <ul id="items" aura:id="items">
        <li>Drag and drop item 1</li> 
        <li>Drag and drop item 2</li> 
        <li>Drag and drop item 3</li> 
        <li>Drag and drop item 4</li> 
        <li>Drag and drop item 5</li> 
        <li>Drag and drop item 6</li> 
    </ul>
</aura:component>
```

I have a static resource called "Dragula" that contains just dragula.min.js and dragula.min.css.

Controller:

```
afterDragulaLoaded : function(component, event, helper) {
    var drag = dragula([document.getElementById("items")]);

    console.log(drag);
}
```

I have tried `document.querySelector("#items")` and `component.find("items").getElement()` to find the elements, and none worked.

The `console.log(drag);` statment returns a full dragula element with an Array(1) under containers, which leads me to believe that it's finding the element.

I have looked at [another SE post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/155996/help-with-using-dragula-in-lightning-components) about this, but that fix is a 2-element drag instance, so their fix wouldn't relate to my issue.

Comment: Do you get any console errors? Anything else that can help us out?

Comment: No errors at all. In experimenting, I put it on a Home page and it worked (after refreshing, if navigating via header to the home page it doesn't). But on a record page it doesn't.